# How to save created image to directory on server instead of downloading it on the client

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found some plugin on internet which creates png image from HTML table. But this plugin downloads file through browser. I need to save that file on some directory on the server.

This plugin I have found.
[Link for plugin download](http://w3lessons.info/export-html-table-to-excel-csv-json-pdf-png-using-jquery/)

This is my html table code:

```
<a href="#" onClick="doExport('#countries', {type: 'png'});"> <img src='icons/png.png' alt="PNG" style="width:24px"> PNG</a>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="countries">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Number</th>
          <th scope="col">Full Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Working time</th>
          <th scope="col">Pause</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>Mark</td>
          <td>07:00-17:00</td>
          <td>30 min</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">2</th>
          <td>Jacob</td>
          <td>07:00-17:00</td>
          <td>30 min</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">3</th>
          <td>Larry</td>
          <td>07:00-17:00</td>
          <td>30 min</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

This is js code:

```
function doExport(selector, params) {
      var options = {
        //ignoreRow: [1,11,12,-2],
        //ignoreColumn: [0,-1],
        //pdfmake: {enabled: true},
        tableName: 'Table name'
      };

      jQuery.extend(true, options, params);

      $(selector).tableExport(options);
    }
```

This is my project: [Link to download](https://gofile.io/?c=JRoL4e)

I have worked in file "test/test.html"

Comment: What's the difference between `this plugin downloads file through browser` and `I need to save that file on some directory`?  Do you mean "save that file on some directory *on my server*"?

Comment: I want to save file in folder on server instead downloading it

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a `http` `post` / `put` request to the server with the image as request content.

On the server a backend api server should be listening the any `http` request made from your domain and handle accordingly.